# get route name and meta inside the layout component

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am trying to get the (current route name and meta defined in the router.js) 
, in the layout component or App.vue

in the router.js

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
        meta: { layout: "default" },
      component: () =>  import( './views/dashboard.vue')
    },
]
```

what iam tring to do in App.vue ,

```
   created() {

           console.log(this.$route );
       console.log(  this.$route.meta.layout);
            console.log(   this.$router.params);
            console.log(  this.$currentRoute);
},
```

and nothing seem to work

Comment: How does your App.vue looks like, specifically the template part.

Comment: so simple only (myheader) component and router-view

Comment: Have you try to put it in the mounted instead of created ?

Comment: yes I tried in mounted